# Reference column with column header and advanced filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to reference a column using column header “Name” on a another sheet “Excel Input” as the column number changes every month.

Upon referencing, I would like to apply advanced filter on that column for displaying the unique values only on to another sheet name “Dashboard” starting from cell J2.

Please advise if anyone can, I’m still new at this. Trying to learn and reference.

```
sheets("Excel Input").Table("Excel_Input").Columns("Name").Advancedfilter Action:=xlfiltercopy, CopytoRange:=Range("J2" 
_ ) , Unique:=True
```

Comment: Maybe you can include your attempt (in your question) so people can find the error?

Comment: As edited above, please advise

Comment: well the obvious mistake is that there is no such thing as `x1filtercopy` - that `1` is supposed to be an `L` - you know... for XL/Excel

Comment: sorry i meant l, typo. But it does not work tho. Edited it to L

Comment: Also, you did not close your quote here: `"Excel_Input)`

Comment: edited it as well but not sure if the whole rationale is correct?

Comment: Is `Excel_Input` a variable name or the literal name of the table on the worksheet `"Excel Input"` ?

Comment: the sheet name is a "Excel Input". the table name is "Excel_Input"

Comment: So to give more info, the table is a named table. But the column "Name" might not be the same column, which is why i want to make it dynamic, and filter based on column name instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Worksheets("Excel Input").ListObjects("Excel_Input").ListColumns("Name").Range.AdvancedFilter _
      Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
      CopytoRange:=Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("J2"), _
      Unique:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use formulas instead of VBA. this does pick up an extra 0 at the end you would have to drop though: [screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyF9l.png)